# call await method after callback

Tags: javascript, callback, async-await

I have a function that calls a method via callback. When the promise resolves and returns a value after `then`, I am calling a method via `await` keyword. So it looks like

```
function test() {
  contract.setName(value).send({}).then(async function (data) {
    var result = await this.getResult(data);
  }
}
```

However, I get an error

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'getResult' of undefined

Am I not allowed to use `async/await` method after callback?

Comment: See the linked questions' answers, the problem is that you're using a traditional function, so `this` isn't what you expect it to be. BTW, you could make `test` `async` and make this simpler: `async function test() {
  const data = await contract.setName(value).send({});
  const result = await this.getResult(data);
}` (and be sure whatever calls it handles the fact it returns a promise, including handling rejections).

Comment: If you can't make `test` `async`, then probably don't use an `async` callback for `then` as it doesn't buy you anything (and do handle rejections): `function test() {
  contract.setName(value).send({})
      .then(data => {
          return this.getResult(data);
      })
      .then(result => {
          // ...use `result`...
      })
      .catch(error => {
          // ...handle/report error
      });
}`

Comment: ok so you are saying either match both `async/await` or match `then` right?

Comment: You *can* mix them, because `async` functions returns promises and you can return a promise from a `then` handler, but it probably confuses your meaning. In general, you want to keep it `async` as long as you can and handle the transition from `async` to non-`async` at the outermost level (the entry point of an event handler, for instance), which is also where you handle errors. Happy coding!